# Would pilot-wave gravity reconcile Bohmian mechanics with relativity?

Tags: relativity, gravitational-waves, bohmian-mechanics

I was reading [Can Bohmian mechanics be made relativistic?](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3896068/#!po=92.8571) from 2016 that attempts to reconcile Bohmian mechanics with relativity. It’s conclusion says:

> Is such a theory then fundamentally—and/or seriously—relativistic? This is not an easy question to answer, because it is not at all clear what, exactly, fundamental/serious compatibility with relativity does, or should, require.

However, it doesn’t mention anything about gravity. So I read [A Pilot-Wave  Gravity and the Titius-Bode Law](http://www.isaacpub.org/images/PaperPDF/NHMP_100022_2018010215195009777.pdf) from 2018 about reconciling the pilot-wave interpretation with the Titius-Bode Law by developing a theory of quantum gravity they call “pilot-wave gravity”.

> **Abstract**.  Since its initial proposal in 1766, Titius-Bode empirical law  has remained a puzzling source of discomfort  as it predicts the average distances from  the planets to  the Sun for no  apparent reason. Using a framework  analogous to de  Broglie’s pilot wave theory  and  the self-organizing Principle of Eurhythmy, we claim  that  several main physical quantities describing  the Solar System are quantified. Hence the Titius-Bode Law is a direct  manifestation  of gravitational pilot-waves at work in the Solar System.

[According to one of the authors](https://www.sciencealert.com/mind-bending-new-theory-of-everything-suggests-there-s-a-hidden-force-that-controls-our-universe):

> "General relativity, on the other hand, must accept that gravitational phenomena can only be fully described if one also applies a wave model. In other words, there will be some aspects best described using general relativity and others best described using pilot wave gravity," said Castro.

Would pilot-wave gravity reconcile Bohmian mechanics with relativity? Would such a theory actually disprove Copenhagen’s interpretation?

Comment: Are you asking if the paper you mention (re the Titus-Bode Law) is a proper theory of quantum gravity ?

Comment: @StephenG Not exactly. I would like to ask that if it’s a proper question for this site. I’m asking if it would make Bohmian mechanics relativistic. In other words, does the paper from 2018 answer the question posed in 2016?

Comment: @Qmechanic Can I ask why this question has been put on hold as off topic? OP's main source is a published, peer reviewed, journal article. Bohmian mechanics, although unpopular among physicists, gives the same predictions as standard QM, so I can't see how trying to unify QM and Gravity using Bohmian mechanics methods should be instantly flagged as off topic. Not unless you were gonna ban all other topics trying to unify QM and GR as well, e.g. LQG and String theory.

Comment: think you have excellent point about the article being apparently mainstream under those criteria. would like to see question stay open but so called "self-organizing Principle of Eurhythmy" sounds highly questionable from mainstream pov. btw site policy on nonmainstram physics seems to be unaware of the thorny philosophy behind that supposed reasonable restriction eg/ aka https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demarcation_problem

Comment: @enumaris: Partly because the link is non-mainstream.

Comment: @Qmechanic which link? The OP provided 1 link to motivate his question which was to a conference proceedings, 1 link he was actually asking about which, as I mentioned, is a published, peer reviewed, journal article, and 1 link to clarify his question which is to a pop-sci journal admittedly, but the quote he used from it is a direct quote from one of the authors of the peer reviewed journal article.

Comment: The journal "New Horizons in Mathematical Physics" does not appear to be a reputable journal by any stretch of the imagination. Its publisher was listed on Beall's list of predatory journals and publishers when it still existed (you can find copies of it if you look around the internet) and the [Editorial Board](http://www.isaacpub.org/EditorialBoard.aspx?ids=19) is not consistent with the list of editorial activity on the named researchers homepages, e.g. https://www.city.ac.uk/people/academics/yang-hui-he#profile=activities and http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~wma3/.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I would argue that this is critical information that should have been given at the time of this question's closing. Given only the generic "put on hold as off topic" message, it is unreasonable to expect the OP to understand why his question was closed.

Comment: @Qmechanic I see why the question was put on hold. Would it be okay to ask any questions about this paper, since it could just be unfortunate that the authors were scammed? If not, would “Have there been any developments toward a pilot-wave interpretation of quantum gravity?” be an acceptable question?